Ignoring text at the start of a CSV file
I'm trying to download a CSV file from the web. However, the first 20 lines are column definitions with the data starting at line 24 (the lines in between are blank).
The code I have is:
data = pd.read_csv(fileURL, skiprows=[23], on_bad_lines='skip')
What's returned are the column definitions as a two-column dataframe and the 20k rows of data are ignored
Without the - on_bad_lines - I get an error as the initial text is two column width whereas the data is 18 columns

skiprows[23] - doesn't skip over the column definitions
The order of the two switches doesn't make a difference.

skiprows on its own raises the 'Error Tokenizing Data' error
Any suggestions?

could you try to reproduce both errors with the smallest csv possible and post it? if you add the necessary python code, it would make a good [mre]

skiprows=[23]. shouldn't that be skiprows=range(24). I'm not super familiar with pandas, but skiprows being a list implies it is exactly skipping the rows you provide. So, [23] likely means "skip row 23 only"

I just checked, I am correct. However if you changed it to skiprows=23 it will skip the first 23 lines of the file. read csv docs

You can find the answer here, too. There is also a skip_blank_lines=True, therefore the empty lines must not be skipped extra.

skiprows=[23] will ignore the 24th line whereas skiprows=23 will ignore the first 23 lines

It took a bit of trial and error and reading through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html but the answer lay in 'header'. However, I had to play with the number, reducing is sequentially to get the data to be seen with the column names.
 data = pd.read_csv(fileURL, header=20)
This works out strange as the column definitions are rows 1-3, 6-22 with the data column names row 24 and the data from row 25 onwards (empty rows in between those number ranges). So, I don't know how the 20 was calculated by Python
[Edit]: Got it. Python ignores the empty rows. 1-3 and 6-22 is 20 rows meaning the data starts on row 21 (although this is actually row 24) and the data from 22 onwards.

skip_blank_lines=True is the default for read_csv. This is why blank lines are being skipped. Also, rows start at 0, not 1. All of your numbers above are 1 higher than the actual number.

data = pd.read_csv(fileURL, skiprows=[23], on_bad_lines='skip')

When read_csv skiprows is list it is understood as

Line numbers to skip (0-indexed)

thus above code means ignore line number 23. If you want express ignore 23 first lines then write
data = pd.read_csv(fileURL, skiprows=23, on_bad_lines='skip')

